# file_managed not working when i try to save permanently

Tags: forms, files

First of all, i want to say that i tried everything, i have coded since 10:30 am and i cannot get the solution, i looked in forums, combined code and many other things and nothing seems to work. What i want to achieve is to save permanently an uploaded image to a carrousel but in one minute (default is six hours but i changed it) the image dissapear. I would appreciate any help you can do.

This is the code.

```
function participacionciudadana_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('participacionciudadana Theme Settings'),
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['show_front_content'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Show content and sidebar on front page'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('show_front_content','participacionciudadana'),
    '#description' => t('Check this option to show content and sidebar on the front page.'),
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['breadcrumbs'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Show breadcrumbs in a page'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('breadcrumbs','participacionciudadana'),
    '#description'   => t("Check this option to show breadcrumbs in page. Uncheck to hide."),
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Front Page Slideshow'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slideshow_display'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Show slideshow'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('slideshow_display','participacionciudadana'),
    '#description'   => t("Check this option to show Slideshow in front page. Uncheck to hide."),
  );
    $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('You can change the description and URL of each slide in the following Slide Setting fieldsets.'),
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Slide 1'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide1']['slide1_desc'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Slide Description'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('slide1_desc','participacionciudadana'),
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide1']['slide1_url'] = array(
    '#title'        => t('Custom Image File'),
    '#type'         => 'managed_file',
    '#description'  => t('Upload a custom image for your site.'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('slide1_url'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://imagessliders',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array("png jpg jpeg gif"),
    ),
    );


  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Slide 2'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide2']['slide2_desc'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Slide Description'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('slide2_desc','participacionciudadana'),
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide2']['slide2_url'] = array(
    '#title'        => t('Custom Image File'),
    '#type'         => 'managed_file',
    '#description'  => t('Upload a custom image for your site.'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('slide2_url'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://imagessliders',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array("png jpg jpeg gif"),
    ),
    );


  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide3'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Slide 3'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide3']['slide3_desc'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Slide Description'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('slide3_desc','participacionciudadana'),
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slide3']['slide3_url'] = array(
    '#title'        => t('Custom Image File'),
    '#type'         => 'managed_file',
    '#description'  => t('Upload a custom image for your site.'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('slide3_url','participacionciudadana'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://imagessliders',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array("png jpg jpeg gif"),
    ),
    );


    $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['slideshow']['slideimage'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('Los nombres tienen que ser foto1, foto2 y foto3 sino no funcionará. Las medidas tienen que ser 930 x 320'),
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['footer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Footer'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['footer']['footer_copyright'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Show copyright text in footer'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('footer_copyright','participacionciudadana'),
    '#description'   => t("Check this option to show copyright text in footer. Uncheck to hide."),
  );
  $form['participacionciudadana_settings']['footer']['footer_credits'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Show theme credits in footer'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('footer_credits','participacionciudadana'),
    '#description'   => t("Check this option to show copyright text in footer. Uncheck to hide."),
  );

$form['#submit'][] = 'participacionciudadana_form_system_theme_settings_submit';

}


function participacionciudadana_form_system_theme_settings_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
      $image_fid = $form_state['values']['slide3_url'];
      $image = file_load($image_fid);
      if (is_object($image)) {
      // Check to make sure that the file is set to be permanent.
      if ($image->status == 0) {
      // Update the status.
      $image->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
      // Save the update.
      file_save($image);
      // Add a reference to prevent warnings.
      file_usage_add($image, 'participacionciudadana', 'slide3_url', 1);
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is specifically deleting the file after it has been uploaded.

A good example to follow is the [image example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/image_example!image_example.pages.inc/7). Check out the form and submit functions of that.

You start of the same where you load the image, set it to permanent and then save it, although maybe

```
    if ($image->status != FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT) {
```

would be better than

```
    if ($image->status == 0) {
```

Then you add file usage, which is also good.

But then you remove the file usage and delete the file.
I'm not sure why seeing as that kind of defeats the purpose of uploading it in the first place.

I would say that is your problem. Try not deleting it.

**Edit:**

Oh I see another issue.
Your use of

```
$image_fid = $form_state['slideshow']['slide3']['slide3_url'];
```

seems wrong.

If you interrogate the [$form_state array](https://www.drupal.org/node/1850410) and reference with the image example you can see there is a `$form_state['values']`, which is where you should be getting your image fid from.

It probably should be this:

```
   $image_fid = $form_state['values']['slide3_url'];
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, i have made all the changes you posted but the problem persist. I don't know what is causing this yet.

Comment: I added some more info.

Comment: I noticed that i put the function submit inside the alter function, i put the two functions separate but it's not working either...